# Website is loading with corrupted data once a while

Tags: php

I have pushed one of my site to LIVE, but once a while when a page loads it is being displayed as below snapshot, but after sometime it gets corrected automatically.

Can one please tell me what could be the reasons for this and how can i make sure to fix this issue so that it is not repeated in future.

[image]

Have also used the security plugin "iThemesSecurityPro" to protect my website from malware.

WordPress version used is 4.7.5

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the compressed content (GZIP maybe). If you have GZIP enabled for your website (on the server, or through some cache plugin), it can explain this. And the reason for you to see it, might be caused by the output being cut so that it can't be uncompressed. This can be due to client-server connection failing, some unrelated server issue, or issue with the cache plugin. It is hard to know exactly, but you should check the cache plugin first.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Yes, GZIP seems to be enabled. Could this be the root cause of the issue?

Comment: Most websites use GZIP by default (all mine websites do), and I have never seen the corrupted output in the browser like this.

Comment: One more question, If there are any syntax issues or javascript errors, if we have enabled the GZIP compression, will that result in such a error intermittently?

Comment: That is unrelated.